# In TextWrangler for Mac OS X, how to change the selected text to lowercase using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, script, textwrangler

I know how to use the menu to change case, but I want it to be a keyboard shortcut. Other text editor have this feature but I would prefer to stick with TextWrangler.

Does one already exist or is there another way, such as a Preference setting or an existing Applescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that by setting a Menu Item shortcut key.

[image]

Under Snow Leopard, go to System Preferences > Keyboard

Click on the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab, the the "+" sign at the bottom to assign a new shortcut.

In "Application", choose "TextWrangler", for "Menu Title", type "Change Case", and put in your desired keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Your TextWrangler "Text" menu item should now show a new "Change Case" option with the keyboard shortcut assigned.

**For Leopard 10.5, it is the same procedure, just that you go to System Preferences > Keyboard & Mouse, instead of System Preferences, Keyboard.**